# Solution for Modular Fibonacci works for small integers but not for big ones

Tags: java

I'm working in a solution for problem 10229 of UVa (Modular Fibonacci) and the code works well for small integers but for big inputs (n = 2.147.483.647, for exemple) the program seems to be stuck. I checked to see if methods *multi* and *pot* could be creating an infinite loop but neither *multi* nor *pot* seem to be the problem. For the input n = 21474836647 and m = 4, *multi* has 49 calls and *pot* has 31 calls which is about right. So, where could the problem be?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Main {
    class Matrix {
        BigInteger[] values;

        public Matrix(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger c, BigInteger d) {
            values = new BigInteger[4];
            values[0] = a;
            values[1] = b;
            values[2] = c;
            values[3] = d;
        }

        public Matrix multi(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
            Matrix result;
            BigInteger[] p = new BigInteger[7];
            BigInteger[] q = new BigInteger[4];

            //Strassen Algorithm
            p[0] = m1.values[0].multiply(m2.values[1].subtract(m2.values[3]));
            p[1] = m2.values[3].multiply(m1.values[0].add(m1.values[1]));
            p[2] = m2.values[0].multiply(m1.values[2].add(m1.values[3]));
            p[3] = m1.values[3].multiply(m2.values[2].subtract(m2.values[0]));
            p[4] = (m1.values[0].add(m1.values[3])).multiply(m2.values[0].add(m2.values[3]));
            p[5] = (m1.values[1].subtract(m1.values[3])).multiply(m2.values[2].add(m2.values[3]));
            p[6] = (m1.values[0].subtract(m1.values[2])).multiply(m2.values[0].add(m2.values[1]));

            q[0] = ((p[4].add(p[3])).subtract(p[1])).add(p[5]);
            q[1] = p[0].add(p[1]);
            q[2] = p[2].add(p[3]);
            q[3] = ((p[4].add(p[0])).subtract(p[2])).subtract(p[6]);

            result = new Matrix(q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3]);

            return result;
        }

        public Matrix pot(Matrix m1, int n) {
            Matrix x;

            // Exponentiation by Squaring (for matrices)
            if (n == 0) {
                return new Matrix(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE);

            } else if (n == 1) {
                return m1;

            } else {
                x = pot(m1, n/2);

                if (n % 2 == 0) {
                    return multi(x, x);

                } else {
                    return multi(multi(m1, x), x);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Matrix inicial, atual;
        int n, m;
        BigInteger M, power;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        inicial = new Matrix(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO);

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            n = in.nextInt();
            m = in.nextInt();


            atual = Matrix.pot(inicial, n);
            power = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(2, m)).toBigInteger();
            M = atual.values[1].mod(power);

            System.out.println(M);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem numbers and course names for your particular school don't mean anything to the rest of the world, even if it's a school as big as UVa. I have absolutely no idea what your program is meant to do and you haven't provided any information other than "it gets stuck". For "stuck" I generally recommend a debugger... have you tried that?

Comment: You should also carefully review your code, and bear in mind that matrix multiplication is not commutative. `m1*m2 != m2*m1`. You are, confusingly, declaring a method `multi(Matrix m1, Matrixm2)` and, from what I can tell, you are returning `m2*m1`, based on my reading of the [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) and what your code is doing. Now, I may well be wrong here - it's very hard to tell from this code, since your p0 to p6 are in a different order from the entries in Wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. The problem I mentioned is [this](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/102/p10229.pdf). And for getting stuck I mean that for small inputs like **11 7**, **11 6** and many others, the program outputs the right answer but for the big example I gave, nothing happens. I reviewed my implementation of Strassen algorithm but it seems to be working fine since it's outputing the same answer as the standard algorithm for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's stuck. I think it takes a really long time. I took your code and added a few lines to determine the running time.

```
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    atual = Matrix.pot(inicial, n);
    power = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(2, m)).toBigInteger();
    M = atual.values[1].mod(power);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long runns = (end - start);
    double runs = ((double)runns)/1000000000.0;

    System.out.println(M);
    System.out.println(runs);
```

Running it with 10,000,000 (ten million) and 4, it takes 4.3 seconds. Running it with twenty million and 4, it takes 11.8 seconds. Fifty million and 4 took 38 seconds. Running with 2,147,483,647? Will take a really long time. Several hours at least.